# javascript local storage find out if exists

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have the following used to create a dummy high score table if if localscores doesn't exist in local storage:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("localScores") === null) {

highscores = [
  {user: "Player 1", score: 100},
  {user: "Player 2", score: 90},
  {user: "Player 3", score: 80},
  {user: "Player 4", score: 70},
  {user: "Player 5", score: 60},
  {user: "Player 6", score: 50},
  {user: "Player 7", score: 40},
  {user: "Player 8", score: 30},
  {user: "Player 9", score: 20},
  {user: "Player 10", score: 10}
  ];
  localStorage['localScores']=JSON.stringify(highscores);
  console.log("doesn't exist")
}

else{
highscores = JSON.parse(localStorage['localScores']);
console.log("exists")
}
```

I always want to maintain 10 scores so I have this to add a score, where username and total are the name entered and score achieved:

```
highscores.push({user: username, score: total});                               
highscores.sort(function(a,b){ return b.score - a.score});    
delete highscores[10];
localStorage['localScores']=JSON.stringify(highscores);
console.log(highscores);
```

Everything is fine until I reload the game and the first function runs, it seems to add null value to the highscores array. So if I add 5 additional scores I will have 3 null values in the array?

[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, null, null, null, null, null]

This leads me to believe either the line where I evaluate if the localscores exists is wrong
    (localStorage.getItem("localScores") === null)

Or where I delete the 11th element in the array is wrong
        delete highscores[10];

Or there's some other issue I don't see, if anyone knows what's going on I'd very much appreciate some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `delete` on an Array instance, you don't actually make the array shorter, you just replace the value at the specified index with `undefined`.

If the length of `highscores` should always be no greater than 10, and the item to be removed will always be the last, you could simply use `highscores.length = 10`.

You could also use `highscores = highscores.slice(0,10);`, but as jfriend00 pointed out, it does involve the extra overhead of creating a new array.

Although, I feel compelled to mention that the performance hit of creating a new array is really just a drop in the bucket compared to the amount of work the browser will be doing to encode/decode JSON and read/write from localStorage, which is notoriously slow.

Comment: This would work also for trimming the `highscores`:  `if (highscores.length > 10) {highscores.length = 10;}` and this wouldn't be making a copy of the array like `.slice()` does.

Answer (score 3):

You could use highscores.[pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) instead of `delete highscores[10];`